# How do you handle a user logout after connection to Firebase db?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm building an Angular2 app using Firebase and the AngularFire2 library.

How do you handle when a user logs out after an authorized connection is made? For example, a user with a valid account logs in, a connection is made to the "orders" node of my Firebase db, then the user logs out.

I get the below error in the console, which makes perfect sense. But how should I catch this error or otherwise prevent it?

The error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: permission_denied at /orders: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

The relevant code (I think):

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

  private orders$: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  private _pendingOrders$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private _activeOrders$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
    private af: AngularFire,
    private auth: AuthService) {
    this.auth.isAuthed
      .subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        if (this.auth.isAuthed.value) {
          const userId = this.auth.getUserId();
          this._subscribeToUserOrders(userId);
        } else {
          // Somehow unsubscribe here, perhaps?
        }
      });
  }

  _subscribeToUserOrders(userId) {
    const query = {
      orderByChild: 'userId',
      equalTo: userId
    };

    this.orders$ = this.af.database
      .list(`orders`, query);

    this.orders$.subscribe((orders) => {
      // Load pending orders
      this._pendingOrders$.next(orders.filter(o => o.status === 'PENDING'));

      // Load active orders
      this._activeOrders$.next(orders.filter(o => o.status === 'ACTIVE'));
    });
  }

  get pendingOrders() {
    return this._pendingOrders$.asObservable();
  }

  get activeOrders() {
    return this._activeOrders$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `this.orders$.subscribe` will return an RxJS [`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html):

```ts
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

private ordersSubscription: Subscription;
...
this.ordersSubscription = this.orders$.subscribe(...);
```

Which you can use to unsubscribe (you will probably want to emit `null` from your subjects, too):

```ts
if (this.auth.isAuthed.value) {
  const userId = this.auth.getUserId();
  this._subscribeToUserOrders(userId);
} else {
  this._unsubscribeFromUserOrders();
}
...
_unsubscribeFromUserOrders() {
  this.ordersSubscription.unsubscribe();
  this.orders$ = null;
  this._pendingOrders$.next(null);
  this._activeOrders$.next(null);
}
```

Comment: Had to add "if(!this.orderSubscription) return;" to top of _unsubscribeFromUserOrders because of login timing issues, but this worked like a charm.  Thanks!